# Regular Expression not returning expected result in Swift

Tags: regex, string, swift

I hav the following, which gets matches of a string in another string:

```
let a : String = "https://www.example.com"
let b = a as NSString
let regex : NSRegularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\.(.*)\\. || /(.*)\\.)", options: .CaseInsensitive)
let text = regex.matchesInString(a, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, b.length))
return text.map {b.substringWithRange($0.range)}[0].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")
```

The goal is to create a more readable version of the domain name. For instance - https://www.example.com should become: example

But this returns an empty string.

Is there something wrong with my Regular Expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces in your regex pattern.

You are using ||. This does not mean OR in a regex pattern.

You are nesting parens.

I modified your regex and it's doing what you expect.

```
let a : String = "https://www.example.com"
let b = a as NSString
let regex : NSRegularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\.(.*)\\.", options: .CaseInsensitive)
let text = regex.matchesInString(a, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, b.length))
return text.map {b.substringWithRange($0.range)}[0].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")
```

Outputs:

```
"example"
```

Comment: Can one not have an OR operation in a regex pattern?

Comment: Sure.  You use a single |. And don't surround it with spaces. The spaces are characters too and will get matched.